# Example of dataframe not broadcasted while doing a join without changing Spark Properties

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

According to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options), a small `DataFrame` is broadcasted by default if this is a "Hive Metastore table" and the `DataFrame` size is less than `10MB`.

How can I create in local `spark-shell` a table which statistics have not been computed ?

So far I tried df with `spark.read.csv`, `Seq(("SOF")).toDF("name")` and `spark.range(1000)`

```
df.join(df, Seq("name")).explain(true)
```

All of the below dataframes resulted in a `broadcast join`

How can I make a "small" DataFrame (with the size less than `10MB`) which is not broadcasted wihtout changing the property `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to `-1` in a `spark-shell`?

Answer (score 0):

On my local spark cluster this works:

```
scala> val df1 = spark.range(10)
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> val df2 = spark.range(100)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("Id")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#232L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#232L], [id#234L], Inner, BuildLeft
   :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
   :  +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
   +- *(2) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)

scala> val df1 = spark.range(10000000)
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("Id")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#238L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#238L], [id#234L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Range (0, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
      +- *(1) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)

scala> val df2 = spark.range(10000000)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("Id")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Project [id#238L]
+- *(5) SortMergeJoin [id#238L], [id#242L], Inner
   :- *(2) Sort [id#238L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#238L, 200)
   :     +- *(1) Range (0, 10000000, step=1, splits=8)
   +- *(4) Sort [id#242L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- ReusedExchange [id#242L], Exchange hashpartitioning(id#238L, 200)

scala>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately I was more thinking about a small `DataFrame` not getting broadcast. I suspect `spark.range(10000000` to be heavier than `10MB`. Which is not what I am looking for, I will clarify my question. Thank you

Comment: If the dataframe fits within the 10MB value set by autoBroadcastJoinThreshold won't it always be broadcasted? I think the only way to force a SortMergeJoin is to disable this value. You can set `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")` first then run your code and set it back to the default value afterwards.

Comment: Apparently, the DF needs to meet 2 conditions, the `10MB` one, and "Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the command ANALYZE TABLE <tableName> COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been run.". Which I do not fully understand, I would like to find an example when this sentance is not true and the DataFrame is under `10MB` :)